# MariaDB SQL sentence: force order of tables for optimizer

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-execution-plan

I have a rather complex query that takes some 5 seconds to run.

**EDITED: complete code for better understanding:**

```
SELECT  
    AGEID, AGECLIID, CLINombre, CLIEstado,AGEOnline, AGEOnlineCancelacion,  
    IF(CANID>0,'Y','N') AS AGECancelado, ACTIOrden, ACTIColor, ACTINombre,  
    ACTICapacidad, 'Y' AS slotactivo   
FROM  
 ( agenda JOIN cliente on AGECLIID = CLIID AND CLICentro = 'Madrid'  
             JOIN actividad on ACTIID = AGEACTIID  
             LEFT JOIN agcambio on CAMAGEID = AGEID  
             LEFT JOIN agcancelacion on CANAGEID = AGEID  
             ) RIGHT JOIN horario on DIAOrden = COALESCE( CAMDia, AGEDia )  
ORDER BY HORHora, MINMinuto, DIAOrden
```

NOTE: Originally, it was "SELECT FROM horario LEFT JOIN all_the_rest of the query".

This produces the following explain plan:

NOTE: I tried to upload a picture here, but I cannot do it, it just creates a link to the picture.

[explain plan with right join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqD9D.png)

It takes like 5 seconds to execute.

The key here is that the part of the query that retrieves busy slots executed alone takes like nothing. In timeslots (horario) table there are 336 rows (all possible time slots) so it should not take that long to perform the RIGHT JOIN.

1. The explain plan says that first it does an ALL access to timeslots, and after that all the other tables are accessed via INDEX.

So I wanted to change the access order to tables, forcing to access timeslots at the end. I changed the order in the FROM clause changing the JOIN to RIGHT, but the explain plan says the same (and the time to run the query is still 5 sec).

2. Testing things, I have tried to do a STRAIGHT_JOIN to force the table access order and it works, cause it took less than a second to return the rows (probably because it is a join, but it is still significantly faster). But I cannot use STRAIGHT_JOIN cause I need the RIGHT JOIN, and I've read that there is no way to do STRAIGHT in an OUTER JOIN.

The explain plan of the execution with straight join is the following:

[explain plan with straight_join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpKek.png)

3. I have tried to create a view but the result was the same.

So,

a) can I force somehow the optimizer to access the timeslots table the last one?

b) but the question is why it is taking so long, if there are only 336 rows to do a RIGHT JOIN with (150 rows of busy slots).... Maybe this could help me to rewrite the query.

Many thanks in advance for any hint... Meanwhile I'm rewriting the query again and again.... :)

Xavi.

Comment: Please qualify each column with the table it is in.  We can't help if we can't see that info.  Also, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we know the indexes.

Comment: Do you have any index starting with `CLICentro`?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It is used, as the explain plan says (images linked, can you see them? I couldn't add pictures to the post, only link them).

It's not an index matter, I believe. All columns used in joins have indexes, the query is "well" constructed. The explain plan says that indexes are used to access each table, except for horario which is ok, because I'm doing a right join and I need all rows from horario. (continued...)

Comment: The execution is retrieving data from horario and then, for each slot from horario, performing the rest of the query. The best way to do it is the opposite, get all rows from the rest of the query, and then mix it (right join) with horario. But there is no way I can force that, only with straight join, but I cannot do that because I need the outer join....

In any case, I appreciate your help and your time. Actually, I'm rebuilding the process so I can mix data myself in a loop....